# Is there a way I can return a functions definition in Elixir

Tags: elixir

Give I have a module:

```
defmodule Foo do
  def bar(baz) do
    IO.puts baz
  end
end
```

Is there some way that I can return:

```
def bar(baz) do
  IO.puts baz
end
```

I've worked out that I can load the whole definition of module with:

```
Foo.__info__(:compile) |> List.last |> elem(1) |> File.read |> elem(1)
```

But ideally, I'd love to be about to do something like

```
Foo.bar/1.__definition__
#=> def bar(baz) do\n  IO.puts baz\nend\d
```

Comment: I think you need to dig into erlang - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5250587/erlang-how-to-convert-a-fun-object-to-a-string

Comment: So you're asking if it's possible to decompile a function definition?  I think the answer is no.

Comment: I'm still holding out hope, failing that, I might have to look at writing my own.

Answer (score 3):

Elixir is a compiled language.  At runtime the source code is no longer there, it has been complied away to BEAM byte code.  There is no source-level representation of the function at runtime for your code to inspect or retrieve.