# Getting representation of callback

Tags: erlang, elixir

I am trying to get the textual representation of a callback function. That maybe sounds weird :/ but what i want to do is:

```
defmodule Sample do 
 def sample_fn(callback) do 
  # Do something here
  callback.()
 end
end
```

since `sample_fn` is called from a lot of different places with different args I just want to see textual representation of the passed callback function, is that even possible ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5250587/erlang-how-to-convert-a-fun-object-to-a-string (that's for Erlang, but Elixir funs are Erlang funs, so I expect it would work the same)

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov thanks, thats exactly i was looking for